# How to manage hundreds of insertion?

Tags: java, sql, cursor, database-connection

What is the best way to avoid `ORA-0100: Maximum open cursors exceeded` when we cannot change the numbers of cursors ?

Is there a bette way than :

```
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(/* Oracle Driver */);
Statement st = null;
  st = connection.createStatement();
for (/* a lot of iteration with counter */) {

  st.executeUpdate(insertSql);

  if ( counter % 500 == 0) {
    st.close();
    connection.commit();
    st = connection.createStatement();
  }
}
```

Which method call consumes a cursor : to `executeUpdate` or to `createStatement` ?
I think it is the `executeUpdate` method this is why I have made this counter.

For the Oracle I work on :

```
select * from v$version;
```

Result :

```
BANNER
----------------------------------------------------------------
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
PL/SQL Release 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
CORE 11.2.0.1.0 Production
TNS for 32-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
```

Comment: Are you opening a new cursor for each record in the for loop?  nested cursors are generally a poor design...this isn't VB, use SQl as the set based language it's intended as.

Comment: Oups ! No of course... made a mistake on copy-paste ;o)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are closing only every **50th** statement...

```
for (/* a lot of iteration with counter */) {
  st = connection.createStatement(); //you create a statement each iteration!

  //...

  // This whole thing not right here
  if ( counter % 50 == 0) {
    st.close(); // not right here -- will have 49 open statements by now
    connection.commit(); //this too
  }

}
```

You should rather use prepared statements, and batch insert for this amount of data.

```
 PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(insertTableSQL);
 for(<the objects you have>) {

   //set parameters into insert query
   statement.set*.*(1, <paramValue>);

   statement.addBatch(); //add it to the batch
 }

 statement.executeBatch();//execute whole batch
 connection.commit();
```

Comment: Should I do it more often than every 50?

Comment: @Manu **every** created statement **has to be closed**. You have two choices: either create a statement for every a lot of inserts (see answer by **André Santos**), or create 1 statement for 1 insert, and close it appropriately. The emphasis is that there must be as many .close() calls, as there are createStatement() calls...

Comment: Refer to what I have read from the Internet and in the javadoc (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeBatch()), it seems that some Oracle Database does not accept batch and/or prepareStatement ? How could I be sure about the one I use ?

Comment: Versions lower than 8.1.5 don't seem to support it. But I doubt you'd find such anywhere in production... That has been released more than ten years ago... BTW, you can check the actual version with this query `select * from v$version;`

Comment: The one I use seems to be 11.2... maybe there is somewhere an option you can enable/disable prepareStatement and/or batch.

Comment: @Manu 11iR2 is pretty recent, it is almost the newest one (12c is just out). It supports all you want, that is for sure. Also, there is no way to turn off prepared statements or batch inserts. Just try and see, it should work. I disagre with this statement `seems that some Oracle Database does not accept batch`: not just Oracle, but every major DB vendor's product supports these... Don't be afraid, this is not magic, just the way to do bulk inserts from code...

Answer (score 2):

You only need one statement for all actions, so you can create the statement out of the loop.

```
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(/* Oracle Driver */);
Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
for (/* a lot of iteration with counter */) {
  // do some INSERT, SELECT, UPDATE
}
statement.close();
connection.close();
```

Now, inside the loop you can run your queries, for example:

```
statement.executeUpdate("query");
```

Comment: I don't think it is a good answer because this kind of implementation cause the problem I ask for a solution here. Sorry if I seems to be rude.